# Implementing iAd in Apps

Tags: storyboard, iad

I am completely new into this and this is my first app. As I have already done the coding in  using the storyboard, I came to know that implementing iAd using the storyboard is little different than without the storyboard. However, I haven't found any example and followed the  implementation with the storyboard. It looks like it shows the ad but it displays the error. Not sure if ads will be displayed when my app is in the store. Do I also have to change the settings online in my Developer account? Thanks in advance.

"2013-07-25 09:28:52.651 Gurbani-Ujagar[35531:11903] [AppDeveloper]: ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unknown error" UserInfo=0x9143e60 {ADInternalErrorCode=0, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unknown error}
2013-07-25 09:28:53.647 Gurbani-Ujagar[35531:11903] [AppDeveloper]: ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0x7563940 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content}"

Please see my ".h" file.

```
   //
//  JapjiController.h
//  Gurbani-Ujagar
//
//  Created by Ivkaran Sawhney on 7/19/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 IveSingh. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface JapjiController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

@end
```

Below is my ".m" file.

```
//
//  JapjiController.m
//  Gurbani-Ujagar
//
//  Created by Ivkaran Sawhney on 7/19/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 IveSingh. All rights reserved.
//

#import "JapjiController.h"

@interface JapjiController ()

@end

@implementation JapjiController {
  ADBannerView *_bannerView;
}

 @synthesize webview;
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
 if (self) {
      // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];

 NSString *pages = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"JapjiSahib"];
 NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pages ofType:@"html"];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
 }
```

Comment: please refer the sample, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html clear the things on create simple banner, frame setup for view controller and ADBannerView then start It will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

what isn't clear with you error message?

I don't see where you alloc and init your ADBannerView

haven't you forgot a

_bannerView.delegate = self; ?

also check you have implemented all method of the ADBannerViewDelegate protocol